# Paypal adaptive payment - preaproval : Start Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, timestamp, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have developed an app using Adaptive payment API, pre-approval.
My platform (ubuntu server, Rails, mysql) is using GMT+4  time.

-->We are the Nov 8.

a/ at 6pm in the afternoon (GmT+4), Start Date for pre-approved payment  from  a user living using GMT +1 is correct and shows Nov 8, but start date for pre-approved payment for a user trying to make a payment from GMT +4  (same time zone as my server) is NOT correct and shows Nov 9

b/ at 9pm in the afternoon (GmT+4), start date of pre-approval for  both users (GMT+4 and GMT +1) is wrong  and shows Nov 9

In case a/ and b/, when  date is NOK, the first screen of paypal when showing login pwd, start date is Nov 8 (correct date), but at 2nd screen to approve payment, this is where the start date switches to Nov 9.

My code:

```
:start_date => Time.now.utc,
:end_date => (Time.now.utc + @project.funding_closed_at.to_i.days).utc,
```

What do you think I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual value of that comes from that date code?

Comment: For the GMT +4 user in case a/, the key (which I received confirmation by email) was generated at 9:49pm (GMT+4). The payment will be processed (so preapproval key will be processed tonight) and will show on mysql database as 2013-11-09 20:00:00 (GMT time) = midnight (GMT+4). I do not think I store the start_date => Time.now.utc somewhere on the system –